# How to add line numbers to the server output in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to add line numbers to the server output in intellij idea?
[image]

Comment: No, use your logger to do this.

Comment: I dont think thats an option

Comment: Then write a plugin for it, implement https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/InputFilter.java.